# How do I get values of a list containing dictionary to compare with another dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my list of dictionary

```
scores = [{'names':'soccer', 'power':'5'},{'names':'football', 'power':6}]
```

as you can see my I may have strings in power values.

My dictionary I want to compare with if names of scores value(soccer) is equal to.

```
my_stats = {'soccer':3, 'football':2}
```

So for example

```
for values in scores:
    if my_stats(index) == "soccer" and scores(names) == "soccer":
        if my_stats(value) < power(value):
            return power(value) is higher
```

I know this code doesn't work, but this is my first time trying to get dictionary values from a list. I am guessing I need 2 for loops for this? 1 for the list and 1 for the dictionary?

Comment: first question. Is `5` supposed to be numeric or string in `'power':'5'`

Comment: it is a string on purpose, so I will have to convert it using int() somewhere in my code when I compare the values

Comment: second question: I think you want to compare values of `names` in `scores` with keys of `my_stats` and return something. What is `power(value)`. I dont see the definition of `power` function or `power` defined as a dict

Comment: if `power` has a value of string, then why is `'power':6` an int? Can it be either int or string?

Comment: the power(value) is just the value of index name 'power'. So first I need to check if my list "scores" index "name" is equal to "my_stats" index name "soccer". If it is that "soccer" value is compared with the power value. It can be either string or int for the values in "power"

Comment: @JTSaiyan--what should the result be?  Meaning, are you looking to check how each score compare to my_stat (i.e. if power in each case is greater)?

Comment: The result is just going to return which one is higher, which isn't a big issue for me to check the condition. The problem was just figuring out how to compare list dict to regular dict values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a few more entries into the `scores` list to make the code more generic.

The below code will scan through the full `scores` list and find the max value of the unique games in `my_stats`.

```
scores = [{'names':'soccer', 'power':'5'},
          {'names':'soccer', 'power':8},
          {'names':'football', 'power':6},
          {'names':'football', 'power':9}]
my_stats = {'soccer':3, 'football':2}

for score in scores:
    for game,power in my_stats.items():
        if score['names'] == game and int(score['power']) > power:
            my_stats[game] = int(score['power'])

print (my_stats)
```

The output of this will be:

```
{'soccer': 8, 'football': 9}
```

The output of your original `scores` list is:

```
{'soccer': 5, 'football': 6}
```

**Expanded code**

You may want to look at this option as well. If the game in `scores` does not exist in `my_stats`, then the below code will also add the game into `my_stats`

```
scores = [{'names':'soccer', 'power':'5'},
          {'names':'soccer', 'power':8},
          {'names':'football', 'power':6},
          {'names':'football', 'power':9},
          {'names':'basketball', 'power':20}]
my_stats = {'soccer':3, 'football':2}

for score in scores:
    if score['names'] in my_stats:
        if int(score['power']) > my_stats[score['names']]:
            my_stats[score['names']] = int(score['power'])
    else:
        my_stats[score['names']] = int(score['power'])

    #for game,power in my_stats.items():
    #    if score['names'] == game and int(score['power']) > power:
    #        my_stats[game] = int(score['power'])

print (my_stats)
```

The above code will give you an output as follows:

```
{'soccer': 8, 'football': 9, 'basketball': 20}
```

Comment: with this code, you can add as many games as you want into `my_stats` and as many scores into `scores`. The code wont change. It will always pick up the max values. You can expand and play with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
for score in scores:
   if score['names'] == 'soccer':
      if score['power'] == my_stats['soccer']
        print('the name is soccer and the scores are even')
```

Let me know if this is what you're trying to do! :)

Note: in general, if you want to compare dictionaries, I'd advise to keep the dictionary keys the same. I'm not sure what your goal is, but for example, I'd change the structure of `scores` to be:

```
scores = {'power':
             {'football': 5, 'soccer': 6}
         }
```

This way you could do:

```
if scores['powers']['football'] == my_stats['football']:
    print('scores are the same')
```

Comment: your code shouldnt restrict the logic to only `soccer`. It should work for any key of `my_stats`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can normalize the `scores` into a similar data structure as `my_stats`.
This can be done like:

```py
>> _scores = dict(zip([item["names"] for item in a], [int(item["power"]) for item in a])
>> _scores
{'football': 6, 'soccer': 5}
```

Then get from the dictionary as usual:

```
>> _scores.get("soccer")
5
```

Comment: what if there are many occurrences of these `{'names':'soccer', 'power':'5'}` in the list `scores` with different values for `power`? You cannot normalize it then.

Comment: @JoeFerndz My first analysis is that the score list should not be having the same names hence such implementation. The original question was not given enough context, though. I have to upvote it to prevent it from having negative point tbh.